# Excluding folders when doing du

Tags: linux, du

I am trying to use `du` to get a list of the files/sizes on the filesystem (doing this as `sudo`):

```
cd /
du --exclude-from="/home"
```

and I am getting an error message, telling me that `/home` is a folder.

I do not want `/home` to be included. Looking through the `du` manual, it does not look like this is possible. What's the alternative to `du` to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things are wrong with your command:-

- You cannot combine `cd` with another command, unless you add `;` between them, eg `cd /; du ...`, though it would be better simply to specify `/` as a positional parameter to `du`, as in `du ... /`.
- The `--exclude-from` specifies a file containing a list of search patterns: what you need is `--exclude` to specify the pattern in-line.

So the command you need is:

```
du --exclude=/home /
```

This will exclude `/home` and all its subdirectories. Note that `du --exclude="/home/* /` will exclude all files and subdirectories, but include the size of the `/home` directory itself.

Comment: My first comment was based on the command as originally seen, but since Kamil Maciorowski's edit I see that it was an error in the formatting of the question.

Comment: I was not trying to combine cd with another command. These are two separate commands, I was trying to show that I had switched to the root folder. Your recommendation works. I had tried that same command, but with the space and / at the end, and it did not work

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Is it not scanning the root directory? Is it not excluding `/home`? It certainly works for me, as it should, though I needed to add `-x` to stop scanning remote file systems.

Comment: `--exclude` does not seem to be an option on OSX although verified it works in Linux.

Comment: @leeman24 - There was no mention of OSX in the original question, and I don't have access to it, so I can't offer a solution for that case.